# Use a class instance as default value in another class' constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor, default-arguments

In C++, I can do something like

```
class CVector3D {
public:
    float x, y, z;
    CVector3D (float x = 0.0f, float y = 0.0f, float z = 0.0f) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
    CVector3D (CVector3D const& other) { x = other.x, y = other.y, z = other.z; }
};

class CMatrix3D {
public:
    CVector3D r, u, f;
    CMatrix (r = CVector3D (1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), 
             u = CVector3D (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), 
             f = CVector3D (0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)) 
        : r(r), u(u), f(f) {}
};
```

In C#, I tried:

```
public class CVector3D
{
    public (float x, float y, float z) coords;
    public CVector3D (float x = 0.0f, float y = 0.0f, float z = 0.0f) => coords = (x,y,z);
}

public class CMatrix3D
{
    public (CVector3D r, CVector3D u, CVector3D f) dirs;
    // variant 1.1
    public CMatrix3D (CVector3D r = CVector3D (1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), 
                      CVector3D u = CVector3D (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), 
                      CVector3D f = CVector3D (0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f))
    {
        dirs.r = r;
        dirs.u = u;
        dirs.f = f;
    }
    // variant 1.2
    public CMatrix3D (CVector3D r = new CVector3D (1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), 
                      CVector3D u = new CVector3D (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), 
                      CVector3D f = new CVector3D (0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f))
    {
        dirs.r = r;
        dirs.u = u;
        dirs.f = f;
    }
    // variant 2
    public CMatrix(
        ValueTuple<float, float, float> r = (1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
        ValueTuple<float, float, float> u = (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f),         
        ValueTuple<float, float, float> f = (0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)) 
    {
        dirs.r = r;
        dirs.u = u;
        dirs.f = f;
    }
}
```

Neither of it works. I know that I would need to do something like

How would I go about what I want?

Comment: As I see it - it doesn't make much sense to provide _some_ of those parameters and leave the other "default" (so, provide only `r` and `u` and leave `f` default). So I'd just add empty constructor which will result in identity matrix (or use separate static property for that) and remove all defaults from current constructor.

Comment: True and a very good point. I am just trying to understand default argument handling in C#. Seems way more complicated than in C++.

Answer (score 2):

As the compiler says: default values must be expressible as compile-time constants, which: this isn't. You *could* use the `null` values to *imply* those values, i.e.

```
public CMatrix3D(CVector3D r = null,
                  CVector3D u = null,
                  CVector3D f = null);
{
    dirs.r = r ?? new CVector3D(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    dirs.u = u ?? new CVector3D(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    dirs.f = f ?? new CVector3D(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

However, I would say that this is actually a prime case for a `readonly struct` (for both types), rather than `class`. I would then probably just have a static `Identity` property that returns the identity matrix. I also probably wouldn't use `ValueTuple` here at all.

Example of what I mean (note: uses C# 10 features):

```cs
using System;

var original = Matrix3D.Identity;
Console.WriteLine(original);

// show manipulation (note: you could also update the original value like this)
var delta = original with { F = new (2,2,2)};
Console.WriteLine(delta);

// to show tuple decomposition
Console.WriteLine(delta.F); // uses our type's ToString
var (r, u, f) = delta.F;
Console.WriteLine($"r={r}, u={u}, f={f}"); // do it ourselves


// record structs are C# 10, note!
readonly record struct Vector3D(float X, float Y, float Z)
{
    public static Vector3D Zero => new();

    public override string ToString()
        => $"({X}, {Y}, {Z})";
}

readonly record struct Matrix3D(Vector3D R, Vector3D U, Vector3D F)
{
    public static Matrix3D Zero { get; } = new();

    public static Matrix3D Identity { get; } = new(new(1, 0, 0), new(0, 1, 0), new(0, 0, 1));

    public override string ToString()
        => $"[{R}, {U}, {F}]";
}
```

Comment: Thank you Marc. Mind adding sample code for the readonly struct solution? I want ValueTuple because vector and matrix coordinates have to be mutable.

Comment: @Razzupaltuff yep, working on it; I would argue, mathematically, that a vector / matrix is absolutely **not** mutable, in the same way that an integer, complex number, quaternion etc is not mutable. You might want to be able to *transform* one matrix/vector to another, but that is not the same thing.

Comment: @Razzupaltuff also: with composition/decomposition operators: you don't need separate support for value-tuples; a vector can *act like* a tuple.

Comment: I am coming from C++, so I may need to adjust my thinking to a different mindset for C#. Assume I have a position vector in some object in a 3D game. In C++, to change the position, I overwrite the old values in the object's position vector. So that vector should be mutable. Same is true for an orientation matrix: When the object's heading changes, I want to change its orientation matrix in place.

Comment: @Razzupaltuff that's up to you - I'll show my example with `readonly` - you're welcome to remove that

Comment: I have no idea yet how to make a vector act like a tuple in C#. :-) I am porting a little 3D app I wrote in Pyhton and C++ to C# to learn the language. I have 30+ years of experience as an SW dev, so I am trying to jump dive right into it.

Comment: One other thing I would like to understand is how to use a value tuple with default values as a function / method argument. I did google for it for two days, but haven't found out about it.

Comment: @Razzupaltuff simple: you cannot; suggestions: 1) use method *overloading* rather than default parameter values; 2) consider using `null` as the default value which is then interpreted internally (in the case of `struct`, this requires `TheStruct?`, i.e. `Nullable<T>`)

Comment: @Razzupaltuff example added, btw

Comment: Thanks. It's just that I don't understand any of this. It looks overly complicated to me, and I have no clue what sense it would make to write it down like this. Not trying to criticize, it's just that I am coming from C++ and have little clue of C#. However, I will ofc google for what you wrote to gain an understanding of it. So I can just new(value, ...) for a record struct, and from the context of CMatrix3D and it consisting of CVector3Ds C# deducts what it has to do? { get; } is a short form to avoid writing a method body?

Comment: @Razzupaltuff probably just as well I didn't show you what the code looks like *without* `record` to do all the heavy lifting, then :)

Comment: I don't understand why one should write that much code for something as simple as it does in the end ... ;-)

Comment: @Razzupaltuff to translate: "define Vector3D as a readonly value-type composed of three floats: X, Y Z" (using "record" basically means: make everything work the way you would expect, without me having to be explicit) - "and Vector3 also has a custom text representation (ToString), and we'll declare a Zero which is the default values of everything" (note we could also provide operators such as binary +, binary -, unary -, etc here if we wanted)

Comment: @Razzupaltuff "I don't understand why one should write that much code for something as simple as it does in the end" - I haven't counted character by character, but: that looks a lot *less* code than the C/C++ version; heck: lose a few features and it can be even shorter: `readonly record struct Vector3D(float X, float Y, float Z);` and `readonly record struct Matrix3D(Vector3D R, Vector3D U, Vector3D F);` - job done

Comment: So you added Zero and Identity mostly because you think vectors and matrices should offer them? Generally yes, I the particular case of my app no. This: "public static CVector3D Zero => new();" creates a CVector3D (you wrote "CMatrix3D", I guess by accident). How would that CVector3D instance's members be automatically zeroed - is that something C# does? Btw, my C++ would be much shorter if I hadn't provided a 2nd constructor to avoid nitpicking by certain SO members, and if it wouldn't accept explicit values and assign them to class instances' members.

Comment: @Razzupaltuff the one time I mentioned `CMatrix3D`, I was still talking about the class-based code in your original question (I would change the name either way, personally; that isn't normal naming in .NET); and yes, I added `Zero` and `Identity` purely because they seemed topical - and in the case of `Identity`: to show how you might conveniently expose the (1,0,0)/(0,1,0),(0,0,1) triad without people having to type it constantly (risking getting it wrong). Re members zeroed: in *classes* fields are implicitly zero initialized; in structs, you normally need to be explicit, but `record` ...

Comment: @Razzupaltuff ...does that for us, via an explicit constructor (compiler-generated, but: it is there); the *default* struct initialization (i.e. `default(Vector3D)` or `new Vector3D()`) simply zeros the memory-space directly, which has the same effect as all zeros

Comment: In your readonly record struct Vector3D there is a line "public static Matrix3D Zero ...". As I said: I am writing a small C# exercise for myself. Should I ever use C# in a professional environment, I would ofc adhere to the naming conventions established there.

Comment: @Razzupaltuff oh that? yes, typo; sorry, fixing

Comment: Yeah, that's what I assumed, np.

Comment: @Razzupaltuff and you're also right in that zero isn't really needed: any of `Vector3D x = default;`, `var x = default(Vector3D);`, `Vector3D x = new();` or `var x = new Vector3D();` : all give you a zero vector (they compile identically - they're just different syntax for the same thing)